# Regex to match not start of line

Tags: regex

I have the following XML tag

```
<list message="2 < 3">
```

I want to replace the `<` in the text with `&lt;`

Need a regex to match `<` if it doesn't appear at the start of line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[^<]+` = one or more characters that are not <

`<` = the < you're looking for

replace:

```
([^<]+)<
```

with:

```
$1&lt;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. This looks like it only matches if the string doesn't begin with a `<` (which it could) and then matches everything up until the first `<` it encounters. Do you have a runnable example in e.g. JavaScript?

Comment: That doesn't match the character, that matches the whole substring from the beginning to the character. I wonder how this can be marked as accepted

Comment: @Davos suggest you try it in something like https://regex101.com/ where you can see it does work. I'm assuming there's at least one character between the opening `<` and the`<` in the middle of the message. I don't state `^` at the start of the regex, so it doesn't exclude lines which start with a `<`

Comment: I stand corrected, this does work on lines that may or may not start with `<` and does exactly answer the question. The other comments above are incorrect. I've deleted my comment above.

Answer (score 34):

Most likely you can do this using lookbehind:

```
/(?<!^)</
```

see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 5):

The dot '.' means "any value"

```
.<
```

Anyway, I suppose you don't want whitespaces, either. If so, then

```
\S\s*<
```

Answer (score 1):

This would give you "<" after the first instance:

```
[^<]<
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<="[^"]*)<(?=[^"]*")
```

Answer (score 0):

@duncan's method works fine if you just want to replacing, but it doesn't match the `<`.
and all the lookbehind wont work if you a using javascript. because javascript doesn't support lookbehind, unless you turn on the `--harmony` flag in nodejs or experimental javascript features in chrome.
But lookahead will work here, which is:

`/(?!^)</`

will match the `<` which is not at the begining of a line.
and the replacing will be:

`'<list message="2 < 3">'.replace(/(?!^)</, '&lt;')`