# Find char not at start of line

Tags: regex, json, grep

How can I search for instances of `{` that are not at the start of the line?

I have a log file that defines an entry as a one line json string. I recently found a bad entry where one entry does not end and another begins. 
`{json:"text.text.text\{json:"more text"}`

I am currently running `grep -l '\\{'` to look for instances of this specific error, but I do not know that a backslash is required for this error to occur.

Comment: This post answers your question in a few different ways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451452/regex-to-match-not-start-of-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use:

```
grep '.{' file.json
```

This will find `{` only if there is a character before it thus not matching `{` when at start of line.

Answer (score 1):

You could specify one or more characters at the beginning of the line:

```
egrep '^.+\{'
```